# How to ignore field,getter method while JSON serialization dynamically without using JSON annotation "@JsonIgnore"

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Need to do `JSON` serialization ignoring some fields,getter methods at runtime without using `JSON Annotation` like "`@JsonIgnore`".

For example :

```
   class xyz{
private int a;
public int b;
...
}
```

I want to ignore instance variable `b` without using Annotation while doing JSON serialization using `ObjectMapper`. How to do this?

```
`ObjectWriter writer   = mapper.writer().withoutAttribute("b");`
```

tried `withoutAttribute()` but it is also not working

Comment: if `b` won't have public getter it will be ignored

Comment: 1.jsonIgonred annotation,2. [Jsonview](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-jsonview-examples/) annotation, 3.   JsonIgnoreProperties annotation. you can achieve this

Comment: @user7294900 what if the field has public getter??

Comment: @AkashShah I can't use Annotations in this case

Comment: Is there any api to do this at Object mapper?

Comment: @user7294900 Annotation is not used since I have to reuse this class for JSON serialization without ignoring the same field. Is there is anyway to do the same at runtime?

Comment: How about using `@JsonSerialize` with a customized serializer?